# jQuery: Simplest method for adding/removing a class between li elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of links, and I would like to use jQuery to set the clicked one as active, and have the rest of them remove their class.

My current setup is like this:

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li id="li_1" class="active"><a href="#" id="link1">link 1</a></li>
  <li id="li_2"><a href="#" id="link2">link 2</a></li>
  <li id="li_3"><a href="#" id="link3">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jquery**

```
$("#link1").click(function () {
  $("#li_1").removeClass('active');
  $("#li_2").removeClass('active');
  $("#li_3").addClass('active');
});
$("#link2").click(function () {
  $("#li_1").addClass('active');
  $("#li_2").removeClass('active');
  $("#li_3").removeClass('active');
});
$("#link3").click(function () {
  $("#li_1").removeClass('active');
  $("#li_2").addClass('active');
  $("#li_3").removeClass('active');
});
```

Obviously this isn't pretty in the least, and I'd like to have it become an extremely simple and flexible 1-2 liner function.  I know this is possible, but unfortunately I don't possess the jQuery-fu that I know many of you do :)

Comment: wow, that's probably the most activity i've seen on any of my questions...thanks all for the great suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('ul > li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Or perhaps better would be to place an ID on the `<ul>` :

```
$('#myUL > li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/parent/
- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: adds the class properly but doesn't remove the existing class

Comment: Was there a `.siblings()` overload added I'm not aware of? :)

Comment: @jAndy, @Nick - Rough morning. :o)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a way to find the links, for example a class or an ID for the `<ul>`, so you'll be able to do

```
$(".theclass").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

(the example above should work if **all the `li`'s have the class `theclass`**; you don't need an ID or class for the `<a>`s)

Comment: Aww you beat me by like, 30 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, I should have extended my answer with multiple solutions. Nevertheless, my answer will be here for others to see and learn from, so it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

use .toggleClass( className ) : - http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Example :

```
$('#foo').toggleClass(className, addOrRemove);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* generic selector, you'd want to give the ul an id or something)*/

    $("ul li a").click(function () {
       $(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
```

Comment: You would want to use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()` here, in a nested `<ul>` situation `.parents()` might have undesirable side-effects :)

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I've edited my suggestion based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try (sorry for edits kept getting syntax wrong):

```
$("li").click(function()
{ 
    $("li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest("li").addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to move the click handler up to the `<li>` in this case (since that's where all the work is happening), like this:

```
$("ul li").click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});​
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Crtxq/).

Comment: isn't it better to leave the click handler on the <a> tag in order to degrade gracefully for browsers without JS enabled?

Comment: @espais - If your links are `#` they'll have no default effect...since this is just styling, what's there to degrade?  If it's on the `<a>` or the `<li>` and JS is disabled, nothing is going to happen either way :)

Comment: the #'s will be replaced with real links as i go on...i probably should have specified that

Comment: @espais - Are the links leaving the page?  In that case again what happens on this page doesn't matter.  If they're *not*, then `click` event on the `<li>` when it bubbles is a perfectly legitimate place to put it, simpler and less DOM traversal as well :)

Comment: they will stay on the same page, but i plan on having them go to a different location (ie page.php?loc=link1 / page.php?loc=link2)